# Programm crashing at fgets() in c

Tags: c, string, file, crash, fgets

when I run my Program, which should read a simple File, it just crashes at the fgets() function. I get no errors in my IDE or from gcc. I know that there are similar Posts, but I couldn't figure out the Problem with them. So here is my code, and thanks for help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char a[64];

int main() {
    FILE* fp;
    fopen("Memory.mem", "r");
    fgets(a, 64, (FILE*)fp);
    printf("%s\n", a);
    // the getchar is just that the Program doesn't close it self imeadiatly
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
//In the Memory.mem file is just "abcdefg"
```

Comment: You're not assigning the return value from `fopen` to `fp`, so it is uninitialized. When you fix that be sure to add code to check if it is not `NULL` before you use it. You don't need the cast of `fp` in `fgets`, and you should `fclose` the file when you're done with it.

Comment: You should get some compiler warnings about using `fp` without former initialization. If not, turn up your compiler warnings. For GCC you can do this via `-Wall -Wextra`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when you `fopen` you don't actually save the returned file pointer.
When you call `fgets` `fp` is uninitialized, thus causing undefined behaviour.

You can fix it by instead of doing this:

```
FILE* fp;
fopen("Memory.mem", "r");
```

do this:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("Memory.mem", "r");
```

Also note that it is good practice to put a check if opening the file was successful.

```
FILE* fp = fopen("Memory.mem", "r");
if(fp == NULL){
    printf("Couldn't open file!\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

And you should close the file once you are done using it with:

```
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Not only is it good practice but it is mandatory to do this check.

Comment: You should consider `return EXIT_FAILURE` rather than `return 0` in case of an error.

Comment: @Dada you're right, I've edited my answer.